# Gmail API authentication and send email using Gmail REST API without redirecting to this screen.

Tags: php, rest, gmail, gmail-api, gmail-imap

I am working on a project, where I need to send emails using the Gmail PHP API. I tried to configure the authentication, and the code worked initially for one email address. But, if I try to reconfigure the same project with a different email address, the gmail is not authorizing with the new email address. I do not know what I am missing so far. This is the code that worked initially.

```
    require '../functions/predump.php';
    require '../vendor/autoload.php';
    require '../database/connection.php';
    require '../database/queries.php';
    require '../database/sample.php';
    $client_id = 'aoppedisano@tecnavi.com';
    $service_account_name = 'anthony@teak-truck-  130612.iam.gserviceaccount.com';
    $key_file_location = 'anthony.p12';
   //var_dump($key_file_location);
   $userid_from='aoppedisano@tecnavi.com';
   $client = new Google_Client();
   //var_dump($client);
   $client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
```

This is the code that worked initially. But now when I try to configure with other email address, I generated the service account key and client ID. I see that it is not configuring. I am not completely sure what the reason is. My only aim is to make the code work through the authentication. Once the authentication part is done, the entire code works. But, I do not know how to make it work. I tried following the google documentation but no help. I tried this link and it worked but, I redirects the screen to gmail login everytime I want to send email. But I do not want that. I want the authentication without redirecting the ui to this page.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WFTi.png)

Comment: You may want to change a setting on Gmail's end and see if that helps.
https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [Quickstart sample](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php), you can store the credentials to disk so you don't have to login every time.

```
// Store the credentials to disk.
    if(!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
      mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
    }
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($accessToken));
    printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
```

> [Authorizing with stored credentials](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server#authorizing_with_stored_credentials):
>
> When users visit your app after a successful first-time authorization flow, your application can use a stored refresh token to authorize requests without prompting the user again.
>
> If you have already authenticated the user, your application can retrieve the refresh token from its database and store the token in a server-side session. If the refresh token is revoked or is otherwise invalid, you'll need to catch this and take appropriate action.

Also found this [thread](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4050/what-causes-the-infinite-redirect-loop-when-i-login-to-gmail-how-do-i-fix-it) which suggested to clear your cookies. You can also try logging in with labs disabled: `http://mail.google.com/mail/?labs=0`. You can also check this related [blog](http://www.ghacks.net/2013/10/29/google-sign-ins-become-tad-difficult-multi-account-owners-now/) which might help.